# How to display text on top of a dialog bubble in arcobjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I am rendering a text glyph with DrawCompoundMarker and I am drawing the dialog bubble with a graphicTracker.Add call, but the text is getting displaced instead of rendering on top of the dialog bubble.  How can I make the text render on top of the dialog bubble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_add_a_balloon_callout/00010000011v000000/

SO is useless for GIS questions I am asking them here now : http://gis.stackexchange.com